# Отправка почты MailApp при условии

Tags: google-apps-script

Доброго времени суток такой вопрос:
Имеется код который, высылает мейл c данными ячейки "var RANGE"
При условии "var check" =10 в функции "if"
Что нужно сделать чтобы:

1. Условие "var check" анализировал не одну ячейку, а диапазон. (Просто
   написать Q123:Q126, не получиться, скрипт не выполняется) и условие
   равно =10 так как триггер запускает функцию каждый
   день, и проверяет таблицу.
2. Если в диапазоне "var check" окажется  цифра 10 то всю строку должно
   выслать мейлом.  Если не получиться, то хоть сделать так>
3. "var RANGE" сделать так что бы можно выборочно взять ячейки (нап.
   B121:N129, R123:T129)

В какую сторону копать!?

```
var ID = "1sBtjJ9x4IKwb9GKu3x3DwoNWTxPej7HJWk5ze8aK"; //speadsheet id
var EMAIL = "Test@gmail.com"; //email 
var RANGE = "Warranty_2021!B121:n129"; //data range to send
var check = "Warranty_2021!Q123:Q123"; //parametr
var text = "Servis"; //subject


function sendData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var data = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(RANGE).getValues();
  var message = {};
  if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getRangeByName(check).getValues() == 10){ //condition
  message.subject = "[La Test] " + text;
  message.to = EMAIL;
  message.htmlBody = dataToHtmlTable_(data) +
    "<br><br>[IT care you ;)]";
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  let quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(quota)
}

Array.prototype.datesToString = function(){
  return this.map(function(row){
    return row.map(function(cell){
      return cell && cell.getTime ? Utilities.formatDate(cell, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd ") : cell;
    });
  });
}


function dataToHtmlTable_(data){
  return JSON.stringify(data, null, "  ")
  .replace(/^\[/g, "<table>")
  .replace(/\]$/g, "</table>")
  .replace(/^\s\s\[$/mg, "<tr>")
  .replace(/^\s\s\],{0,1}$/mg, "</tr>")
  .replace(/^\s{4}"{0,1}(.*?)"{0,1},{0,1}$/mg, "<td>$1</td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам разобрался.
Решение.

```js
var ID = "1sBtjJ9x4IKwb9GKu3x3DwoNWTxPej7"; //speadsheet id
var EMAIL = "Test@gmail.com"; //email 
var RANGE_LUT = "Warranty_2021!B10:Q20"; //data range to send
var text = "Time to ..."; //subject

function sendData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var dataLut = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(RANGE_LUT).getValues();
  var message = {};
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Warranty_2021");
  var colValuesLut = sheet.getRange(11, 16, 10, 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < colValuesLut.length; i++) {
  if (colValuesLut[i][0] == -10) { //condition, value = -10 
  message.subject = "[La test] " + text;
  message.to = EMAIL;
  message.htmlBody = dataToHtmlTable_(dataLut) +
    "<br><br>[IT care you]";
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  let quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(quota)
}
}
```